# Swift 2.0: throw exception within an asynchronous piece of code

Tags: asynchronous, swift2, alamofire

I am trying to implement the log in service for an application, and I would like to throw an exception if the response status code is not equal to 200. I am using Alamofire as HTTP networking library.

```
static func loginWithUsername(username: String, andPassword password: String) throws {

    let action = "SmartShoppers/login"
    let url = baseUrl + action


    Alamofire.request(.POST, url, parameters: ["username": username, "password": password])
        .response { request, response, data, error in
            if response?.statusCode != 200 {
                throw ServiceError.LogInError
            }
    }
}
```

This is the ServiceError enum definition:

```
enum ServiceError: ErrorType {
    case LogInError
}
```

What I want to do deal this exception when it is thrown in a function which is called when a button is pressed. This function is in the ViewController class associated with the ViewController that contains that button. The code that is going to be executed is:

```
do {
    try Service.loginWithUsername(username, andPassword: password)
} catch {
    // SHOW AN ALERT MESSAGE
}
```

Why am I receiving the message `Cannot call value of non-function type 'NSHTTPURLResponse'`? Is it the correct way to implement this service? If not please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closure that you are passing to the `response` method does not include `throws` in its signature, so you will not be able to throw an exception from within it.

IMO this is not a case where you would want to throw an exception, anyways - a non-200 response code is not an exceptional error / failure, and I wouldn't try to use an exception here as a means of control flow.

Comment: How can I include `throws` in the signature? Do I have to enter the Alamofire code?

Comment: that is where you would start, yes -- e.g. if you are using v1.3.1 you would find your `response` function definition here -> https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/1.3.1/Source/ResponseSerialization.swift#L116 -- but again, I would advise against going this route

Comment: You cannot throw in this manner. I would follow @fqdn's advice here. If you want to understand exactly why you cannot throw this way, I'd suggest you attempt to work through an example in a playground where you create an async login method with a completion handler and attempt to make it throw in an async manner. It doesn't work. This is exactly why we use `Result` types in Alamofire.

Comment: I also want to throw an exception. in case of a response different from 200.
My task will be to manage this exception in other method